# Draw partially transparent UIView while using the backgroundColor

Tags: iphone, uiview

I'm creating a custom UIControl that renders it's view via `drawRect:`. I want to use the existing backgroundColor property to permit customization via Interface Builder. However, if the backgroundColor is set, by the time drawRect: is called, the entire rectangle has already been filled in. I have opaque = NO and clearsContextBeforeDrawing = YES. If I set the backgroundColor to clearColor then I can render only the parts that I want.

How do I prevent the UIView from filling in the entire rectangle with the backgroundColor automatically?

I should mention that the custom control is placed in Interface Builder so the initWithCoder: method is being used to instantiate the object.

This should certainly possible as if you inherit from UIButton - which uses the backgroundColor - the rectangle has not been filled in.

Answer (score 2):

You need to overide:

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx;
```

This is where the background color is applied.  If you want the view to handle the background color, call the super's drawLayer method.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a custom control, could you add a variable `UIColor *myColor`, and, in the init method, after it has been read from the nib, set `myColor = self.backgroundColor`, and `self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]`? Then obviously use `myColor` in your drawRect.

I haven't tried this, and it seems a bit ugly, but maybe it works?